# "Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of len function" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ntext

I'm using entity framework and I write this code to get some result from DB:

```
ReviewsDBEntities DB = new ReviewsDBEntities();  
var result=DB.Review.Where(r => r.ReviewText.Length > 200);
```

But I get this error as an inner error: "Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of len function"

I looked it up, and I found out that because the type of ReviewText is defined as ntext, the function Len won't run it on the Database side. Now, I don't know how I can change the code to get ReviewTexts with Length more than 200.

Comment: Your error is pointing to the right direction.  Your underlying type I am guessing is 'text' and should no longer be used.  If you can update that type to be varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).  Entity has a problem with determining length on this old type.  You can do a hack I believe to go '.ToString().Length' and attempt that but that is still not resolving the underlying problem is the type.

Comment: I just wrote '.ToString().Length' and it still didn't work.

Comment: That is too bad, I would suggest changing this data type if possible though even if you do get a proper answer from Jeroen below or someone else.  It is not best practice to use this type and it will limit you in other ways down the road later too.

Comment: @djangojazz I remember the day I changed the type to ntext because I couldn't find any other types to store a large text. Do you recommend any?

Comment: varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) due to the same reasons you are having a problem with in Entity.  By all accounts MS is going to deprecate the type of ntext in the future too so it is a good idea to get rid of it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result=DB.Review.Where(r => SqlFunctions.DataLength(r.ReviewText) / 2 > 200);
```

Why `/ 2`? Because [`DATALENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd487157) returns the length in bytes, and `NTEXT` contains Unicode characters, each of which consume 2 bytes.